# Knockout js expand eleements

Tags: knockout.js

Hi i am very noob on knockout.js

I have the follow fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xrealtv/q7oy15pk/5/

```
            var jsonData = {  check fiddle };
```

how is possible to make a toggle collapse and expand when i click on a Blue tournament or  on red sport?

in the duplicated answer there is the code

```
function Sample(item) {
var self = this;
self.name = ko.observable(item.name);
self.id = ko.observable(item.id);
self.expanded = ko.observable(false);
self.toggle = function (item) {
    self.expanded(!self.expanded());
};
self.linkLabel = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.expanded() ? "collapse" : "expand";
}, self);
}


var data = ko.utils.arrayMap(json, function (item) {
        return new Sample(item); // making things independent here 
    });
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
```

Where i will put it on the fiddle so it will work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout js foreach binding with expand/collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397351/knockout-js-foreach-binding-with-expand-collapse)

Comment: if i could understand this example then i will not called my self a noob.i Am asking for the 10 lines of code so the fiddle will work.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/onf1xrjt/ . if your interested you can refer to one of my answers earlier. make sure you include bootstrap files .